# Set all shipping costs to zero if cart is above 1200 in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get a code that will set my all my shipping cost to zero if cart amount is above 1200 Czech crowns. I tried about 10 codes and plugin and nothing work for me. I cant set standard Free Shipping rate in woocommerce, becouse our local delivery company refresh their delivery points and I need this option in my cart (I attached image with that)
I only need to set all shipping costs to zero if cart is above 1200 CZK. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should find what your looking for on [this page](https://woocommerce.com/document/free-shipping/) of woocommerce documentation

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.